# How to include removed array items when using lodash transform

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm using lodash transform to generate a change message by comparing two objects. I need to detect if an item has been removed from an array and include the item in the change message. How can I push the removed item back onto the changed array?

```js
var lhs = {
  "Income": [{
      "Id": 1,
      "MonthlyIncome": 5000,
      "Type": "Base"
    },
    {
      "Id": 2,
      "MonthlyIncome": 1000,
      "Type": "Overtime"
    }
  ]
};
var rhs = {
  "Income": [{
      "Id": 1,
      "MonthlyIncome": 5000,
      "Type": "Base"
    },
    {
      "Id": 0,
      "MonthlyIncome": 500,
      "Type": "Other"
    }
  ]
};

function difference(base, object) {
  function changes(object, base) {
    return _.transform(object, function(result, value, key) {
      if (!_.isEqual(value, base[key]) || key === 'Id') {
        if (!_.isEqual(value, base[key]) && key === "Id") {

          //The item at this position has been removed,
          //but needs to be include in the change message  
          //How to push this item onto the array ?
          var removedItem = {
            Id: base[key],
            Action: "remove"
          }
        }
        result[key] =
          _.isObject(value) && _.isObject(base[key]) ?
          changes(value, base[key]) :
          value;
      }
    });
  }
  return changes(object, base);
}

var changeMessage = JSON.stringify(difference(lhs, rhs));

console.log(changeMessage);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

**Expected result for changeMessage**

```
{
    "Income": [
        {
            "Id": 0,
            "MonthlyIncome": 500,
            "Type": "Other"
        },
        {
            "Id": 2,
            "Action": "remove"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Stash the `removedItem` in the `result`.

```js
var lhs = {
  "Income": [{
      "Id": 1,
      "MonthlyIncome": 5000,
      "Type": "Base"
    },
    {
      "Id": 2,
      "MonthlyIncome": 1000,
      "Type": "Overtime"
    }
  ]
};
var rhs = {
  "Income": [{
      "Id": 1,
      "MonthlyIncome": 5000,
      "Type": "Base"
    },
    {
      "Id": 0,
      "MonthlyIncome": 500,
      "Type": "Other"
    }
  ]
};

function difference(base, object) {
  function changes(object, base) {
    return _.transform(object, function(result, value, key) {
      if (!_.isEqual(value, base[key]) || key === 'Id') {
        if (!_.isEqual(value, base[key]) && key === "Id") {

          // stash the removedItem to the result
          result.removedItem = {
            Id: base[key],
            Action: "remove"
          }
        }
        result[key] =
          _.isObject(value) && _.isObject(base[key]) ?
          changes(value, base[key]) :
          value;
      }
    });
  }
  return changes(object, base);
}

var changeMessage = JSON.stringify(difference(lhs, rhs));

console.log(changeMessage);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve the same thing with this via lodash:

```js
var ld = { "Income": [{ "Id": 1, "MonthlyIncome": 5000, "Type": "Base" }, { "Id": 2, "MonthlyIncome": 1000, "Type": "Overtime" } ] }; var rd = { "Income": [{ "Id": 1, "MonthlyIncome": 5000, "Type": "Base" }, { "Id": 0, "MonthlyIncome": 500, "Type": "Other" } ] };

const changes = (a,b) => 
  _.filter(_.values(b.Income), x => !_.includes(_.mapValues(a.Income, 'Id'),x.Id))

const compare = (l,r) => {
  var plus = changes(l,r)
  var minus = _.map(changes(r,l), ({Id}) => ({ Id, Action: "remove" }))
  return [...plus, ...minus]
}

console.log(compare(ld,rd))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Same with ES6:

```js
var ld = { "Income": [{ "Id": 1, "MonthlyIncome": 5000, "Type": "Base" }, { "Id": 2, "MonthlyIncome": 1000, "Type": "Overtime" } ] }; var rd = { "Income": [{ "Id": 1, "MonthlyIncome": 5000, "Type": "Base" }, { "Id": 0, "MonthlyIncome": 500, "Type": "Other" } ] };

const ids = d => d.map(x => x.Id)
const changes = (a,b) => 
    Object.values(b.Income).filter(x => !ids(a.Income).includes(x.Id))

const compare = (l,r) => {
  var plus = changes(l,r)
  var minus = changes(r,l).map(({Id}) => ({ Id, Action: "Removed" }))
  return [...plus, ...minus]
}

console.log(compare(ld,rd))
```